# Which setting in visual studio code has changed selection pattern like these?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have accidently changed selection pattern in my Visual Studio Code editor so that selection of code in file has been difficult when I want to copy and paste code. Want to reset selection to normal.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `File -> Preference -> Settings` and search for `Column Selection`. You want that off if you want the default mouse selection. Also, tip: if you have it off, you can always hold down `Shift + Alt` if you want that selection action.